# How to set cookie for localhost to test API in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, cookies, web-api-testing, node-rest-client

I have a web application and I'm writing APIs on NodeJS.

I want to test this APIs use mocha, chai and Node-rest-client and don't open browser, but I have a problem: "**I don't know How to set cookie (Authorization of header) when I ran server on localhost**)

- First, run server on localhost:3000.
- Next, run command api testing (Set cookie to server and run API testcases).

Comment: are you using chrome ?

Comment: you mean `send a request with cookie` or  try to `write cookie in response to browser`?

Comment: @Kalana Demel I use node-rest-client package to send a request after ran localhost in port 3000. ** I don't open browser (I only open browser when develop API)  and I want to send a request with cookie (header) and  node-rest-client will return result of api **

Comment: @chenkehxx I mean send a request with cookie to pass Authorization token of header for API :)

Comment: is your base requrement to set basic auth header so the server will authenticate ?

Comment: @Kalana Demel, yes

Comment: @Tam check updated answer

Comment: @TamVo if you want to send a request with cookie, I think you can try `fetch-cookie` module

Answer (score 0):

If you're using chrome it usuall wont save cookies for loacal host try running the following to run chrome with disabled web security.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --args --disable-web-security
```

**UPDATE**

As in the documentation you can set Auth header with this : [Documentation](https://github.com/aacerox/node-rest-client#basic-http-auth)

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;

// configure basic http auth for every request
var options_auth = { user: "admin", password: "123" };

var client = new Client(options_auth);
```

Comment: Hi @Kalana Demel 
I use node-rest-client package to send a request after ran localhost in port 3000. ** I don't open browser (I only open browser when develop API) and I want to send a request with cookie (header) and node-rest-client will return result of api **